# jqZoom IE 6,7 (8?) bug

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

**EDIT** Page with issue not available anymore

In magento while using IE 6 or 7, the zoom function didn't work for me, I solved this by upgrading to jqZoom Evolution (see answer)

Comment: Try the solution on following link:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284438/jqzoom-ie9-bug-error/9464890#9464890>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the jQzoom from jqzoom v2.2 to jqzoom evolution 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In IE8 is working although calendar-setup.js is issuing some errors on lines:
4022 char 2, 7354, 1590('style' is null or not an object), 4022 ( rest of errors - Object doesn't support this property or method). Try to disable this script if you don't need it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the condition at the start of the plugin from

```
var isIE6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);
```

to

```
var isIE6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <10);
```

It worked well for me.