# jQzoom IE9 Bug - Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9, zooming

I have a problem with the following page.

http://nortlander.dk/frankrig/avoriaz/pistekort/

I have installed the jQzoom plugin, and everything works fine in all other browsers than IE9, are there any know bugs, issues or errors that somone is not telling me about :)

All help would be apriciated. Thanks

Comment: Your site appears to have the issue fixed, can you provide an explanation of what you've done?

Answer (score 4):

i have the same issue. what i did is the following.

```
    if (img[0].complete || $.browser.msie) {
        //fetching data from sallimage if was previously loaded
        smallimage.fetchdata();
        if ($(".zoomPad", el).length == 0) obj.create();
    }
```

it works now.

Comment: This helped me with an issue where hover would only work after you reload the page. Thank you soooo much!

Comment: I had the same problem reported by creativetim and this solved it! 
Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. If you can't found this code part, you can search "            fetching data from sallimage if was previously loaded
" this text. On line  390 in my js file. Thank you @nizzy

Answer (score 3):

jqZoom was not working for me in IE8, So I fixed the problem as follows:
In Stage class => this.append function, there is a variable 'thickness' which is defined inside a condition. I defined it outside the condition and now its working fine for me.

```
            var thickness = 1;
            if (settings.zoomType == 'innerzoom') {
                this.node.css({
                    cursor: 'default'
                });
                thickness = (smallimage.bleft == 0) ? 1 : smallimage.bleft;
                $('.zoomWrapper', this.node).css({
                    borderWidth: thickness + 'px'
                });    
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I replaced jQzoom on big online store with cloud zoom. Everything seems to work fine and a little bit smoother now. Maybe you'll like it too:
http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm